# How do I configure the /cloudbuild.yaml file to trigger /module1/cloudbuild.yaml file to build the project

Tags: git, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, monorepo

> Blockquote

- .gitignore
- .git
- cloudbuild.yaml
- module1/cloudbuild.yaml
- module1/some_project_related_files
- module1/app.yaml

> Blockquote

Need to trigger that rooted cloudbuild.yaml file when build started and that rooted cloudbuild.yaml file will trigger the module1/cloudbuild.yaml to build that project and follow the all steps which is in module1/cloudbuild.yaml file.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply trigger it into the main `cloudbuild.yaml` by adding this step where you want

```
 - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
   args: ["builds","submit","--config=module1/cloudbuild.yaml"]
```

Be careful, the whole project tree will be copied (I mean root file + `module1` directory). For preventing this, you can customize the step by triggering the cloud build directly from the `module1` directory

```
 - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
   entrypoint: "bash"
   args: 
     - "-c"
     - |
         cd module1
         gcloud builds submit
```

Here, only the file of `module1` directory will be copied into the new Cloud Build job.

Then, take care of [the timeout](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#timeout_2) of the first job if the 2nd one takes time.

Last warning about cost. Here you are running 2 jobs. 1st run and trigger the second one. During the execution of the 2nd, you will be charged on the execution on the 2nd but also on the first one because it is still active.

Comment: I found a error `ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) INVALID_ARGUMENT: invalid build: key in the template "_ENVIRONMENT" is not matched in the substitution data; substitutions = map[]` while using your provided step.

Comment: Maybe, I don't know the content of your cloudbuild.yaml. If it required a substitution variable, pass it in parameter by adding this param which get the initial param of the 1st cloud build `--substitutions=_ENVIRONMENT=$_ENVIRONMENT`